# How do you use instead of the arrow function syntax?

Tags: javascript, filter, arrow-functions

I have encountered several problems relating to the arrow function and, after a simple google search or two, I fixed them.

Then I encountered this:

```
this.projectiles = this.projectiles.filter(projectile =>projectile.markedForDeletion);
```

I got an error saying that "'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 which is not supported by this environment."
I did several google searches and still don't know how to fix it.

I tried to repace the arrow with this:

```
this.projectiles = this.projectiles.filter(function(projectile) {});
```

But I need to input the

```
!projectile.markedForDeletion
```

into the code, but I don't know where or how.

Can someone please help?

Comment: `function(projectile) {return projectile.markedForDeletion}` - not sure why you'd want to change `projectile.markedForDeletion` to `!projectile.markedForDeletion` - though, you've failed posting code in the question so perhaps there's some typos

Comment: in general `x => x.y` is short for `function(x) { return x.y; }`

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent for:

```js
this.projectiles = this.projectiles.filter(projectile => projectile.markedForDeletion);
```

without arrow functions would be:

```
this.projectiles = this.projectiles.filter(function(projectile) {
  return projectile.markedForDeletion;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions can employ a [*concise body*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body), which is just an expression, and this expression is implicitly returned. Example:

```js
const isProjectileNotMarkedForDeletion = (p) => !p.markedForDeletion;
```

The equivalent block body would look like this:

```js
const isProjectileNotMarkedForDeletion = function (p) {
  return !p.markedForDeletion;
};
```

Here's a runnable code snippet demonstrating using these functions inline for the callback argument to an `array.filter` method invocation. They achieve the same result:

```js
const projectiles = [
  { id: 1, markedForDeletion: true  },
  { id: 2, markedForDeletion: false },
  { id: 3, markedForDeletion: true  },
  { id: 4, markedForDeletion: true  },
];

const filtered1 = projectiles.filter(p => !p.markedForDeletion);

const filtered2 = projectiles.filter(function (p) {
  return !p.markedForDeletion;
});

console.log(filtered1); // [{ "id": 2, "markedForDeletion": false }]

console.log(filtered2); // [{ "id": 2, "markedForDeletion": false }]

console.log('equal:', JSON.stringify(filtered1) === JSON.stringify(filtered2)); // "equal: true"
```